# Logrotation when filenames includes date

Tags: log-rotation

My log files are in the format "2011-03-28.log.php". Log files are created every day. I want to keep 5 days log and rest I want to remove it, which means only
5 log files will be kept and rest everything will be deleted.

Is it possible using Linux logrotate ?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Look at the rotate option in the config file. 
http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

If you set it to rotate daily, and keep 5 files, then it will only keep the last 5 long files. Also, since your file name changes, look at the wildcard section of the above man page.

You can also do this.

```
find /pathtologs/* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

This will delete anything with a modification time of longer then 5 days.

Comment: I am aware of find, but the same is it possible through logrotate ?

Comment: Looks to be. Can't say for sure as I have not done it. But from reading the man page, posted above, you can do it.